# C# CopyBlock vs CopyBlockUnaligned use cases

Tags: c#, memory, unsafe

So I am learning about cryptographic hash functions and their implementations in particular. As C# is my language of choice I decided to create a crypto library for .NET Core. Sooner or later I had to use some unsafe code for some performance optimizations.

As to be expected I have to copy a lot of memory around. Up until now I always used `Unsafe.CopyBlock()` for this. However there also seems to be a function called `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()`. Sadly the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.copyblockunaligned?view=netcore-3.1) isn't too detailed about the differences between the two (except that `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()` *"doesn't assume architecture dependent alignment of the addresses."*)

Now I'm wondering: Are there any benefits in choosing for example `Unsafe.CopyBlock()` over `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()` or do they have completely different use cases? If so when should I use which? It'd be nice if someone could explain the differences between the two or point me to some documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stumbling about `Unsafe.CopyBlock()` and `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnalinged()` a second time I finally decided to take a look at [the source of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9860ffd615ddd7c255f6183b1ace18bd9ed3e8f8/src/libraries/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il#L176).

Comparing the IL of `CopyBlock()`

```
.method public hidebysig static void CopyBlock(void* destination, void* source, uint32 byteCount) cil managed aggressiveinlining
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 )
    .maxstack 3
    ldarg.0
    ldarg.1
    ldarg.2
    cpblk
    ret
}
```

with the code of `CopyBlockUnaligned()`

```
.method public hidebysig static void CopyBlockUnaligned(void* destination, void* source, uint32 byteCount) cil managed aggressiveinlining
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 )
    .maxstack 3
    ldarg.0
    ldarg.1
    ldarg.2
    unaligned. 0x1
    cpblk
    ret
}
```

We can see that the only noticable difference is the `unaligned. 0x1` right before the call to `cpblk` in the `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()` implementation. As I'm not too fluent in IL taking a look at [the documentation of `System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Unaligned`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unaligned?view=net-5.0) reveals the definition of the `unaligned` keyword:

> Indicates that an address currently atop the evaluation stack might not be aligned to the natural size of the immediately following `ldind`, `stind`, `ldfld`, `stfld`, `ldobj`, `stobj`, `initblk`, or `cpblk` instruction.

and further down it states

> Unaligned specifies that the address (an unmanaged pointer, `native int`) on the stack might not be aligned to the natural size of the immediately following `ldind`, `stind`, `ldfld`, `stfld`, `ldobj`, `stobj`, `initblk`, or `cpblk` instruction. That is, for a `Ldind_I4` instruction the alignment of the address may not be to a 4-byte boundary. For `initblk` and `cpblk` the default alignment is architecture dependent (4-byte on 32-bit CPUs, 8-byte on 64-bit CPUs).

Therefore it is safe to say that `Unsafe.CopyBlock()` should only be used when we know that both source and destination addresses are aligned which currently [only *inofficially*](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33228) includes addresses returned by `Marshal.AllocHGLobal()`. However the upcoming .NET 6 (currently in preview) will bring us [`NativeMemory`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6444#issuecomment-880864626) to control memory alignment ourselves which would allow us to use `Unsafe.CopyBlock()` more freely. So if unsure about the alignment just using `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()` is recommended.